# Checking for a series of uniform non-zero digits

Tags: python, beginner

```
def standvastig(reeks): 
    """
    Checks if the given input (list or number) is a series of one number (eg. 444444, 2222, etc.)
    Remark: raise an error if the input is a series of 0s or non-integers

    >>> standvastig(44444444)
    True
    >>> standvastig('44544444')
    False
    """
    if str(reeks).isdigit() == False or int(str(reeks)) == 0:
        raise AssertionError('ongeldig serienummer')# gives an error when the input is not a list of integers or 0s

    if any([str(reeks) == '1'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '2'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '3'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '4'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '5'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '6'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '7'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '8'*len(str(reeks)), str(reeks) == '9'*len(str(reeks))]):
        return(True)
    else: return(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Can this code be written more pythonic? Mainly the if condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While thinking about the "are all of the digits the same as the first digit?", I realized I could just do it like this:

```
    if len(set(reeks)) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I also changed the multiple str(reeks). Thanks!

Edit:

Could be done even better:

```
return len(set(str(reeks))) == 1
```

Thanks to Graipher!

Comment: Why not just `return len(set(str(reeks))) == 1`?

Comment: `return` is a statement, not a fuction, so please say `return x` rather than `return(x)`

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of suggestions for you to implement:

- You convert `reeks` into a string far more frequently than is necessary; just do it once, at the top of the function.
- The correct exception to raise if a value is not acceptable is `ValueError`.
- Rather than `thing == False`, you can use the more readable `not thing`.
- Your approach to the solution seems strange to me; rather than *"are all of the digits one, or are all of the digits two, or are all of the digits..."*, why not *"are all of the digits the same as the first digit"*?
- Python has a [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which discourages e.g. redundant parentheses and multi-statement lines:

  ```
  else:
      return False
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So looks like you are creating all the possible permutations that would be acceptable for a input of a certain length. e.g. for a input of length 3 you'd create the strings ['111', '222', ..., '999'].

You could create those permutations a little more succinctly with a list comprehension using a range [1-9] (range is inclusive of the first value and exclusive on the second) and multiply each one of those integers in the range by the length - as you were doing before. You can then just check to see if the input is in the acceptable results:

```
allowed_permutations = [i * len(reeks) for i in range(1, 10)]

if reeks in allowed_permutations:
    pass
```

Alternatively, you could verify that the given input meets your requirements instead of producing all possible results. I got a little carried away and this is quite a defensive function but gives you better error handling (using the appropriate Python exceptions) and what is still, hopefully, quite easy to read:

```
def standvastig(seq):
    # convert int to an Iterable
    if type(seq) is int:
        seq = str(seq)

    if not isinstance(seq, Iterable):
        raise ValueError('Iterable or int required')

    try:
        seq = [int(d) for d in seq]
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Sequence must be all numeric')

    try:
        first = seq[0]
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError('Sequence must have atleast one element')
    else:
        all_same = all(d == first for d in seq)
        all_zero = all(d == 0 for d in seq)
        return all_same and not all_zero


standvastig('1111111')  # True
standvastig([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])  # True
standvastig('1111121111')  # False
standvastig(22222222)  # True
```